# Get user location on map?

Tags: android, eclipse, google-api, android-sdk-2.1, android-maps

I have a map view that zooms and places markers. I to get the users location on start up. How would I go about doing this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
   GeoPoint geoPoint = new GeoPoint((int) (your_location_variable.getLatitude() * 1E6),(int) (your_location_variable.getLongitude() * 1E6));
    mapController.animateTo(geoPoint);
```

Answer (score 0):

By on startup - I assume its application start up. Just register a LocationListener before you have your map view displayed. The callback to the LocationListener should give you the current co-ordinates. You can now use these co-ordinates to place markers.